# Probability that at least one of the bullets will go on forever.

Tags: probability

There's a gun located on an infinite line, let's say at 0 on number line.
It starts shooting bullets along that line, `+X axis`, at the rate of one bullet per second.

Each bullet has a velocity in the range **[0, 1]** m/s randomly chosen from a uniform distribution. 
If two bullets collide (are at the same spot at the same time) they explode and disappear.

What is the probability that at least one of the *infinite* bullets will infinitely fly without colliding with another bullet?

Comment: Hint: what happens in there is a long subsequence that is monotonic increasing in velocity?

Comment: Intuitively I think the probability is 0, there will always be infinitely faster bullets.

Comment: Further hint: There is a zero-one law that is applicable here

Comment: This question was asked a while back on [brainden.com](http://brainden.com/forum/topic/16908-gun-with-unlimited-bullets/)

Comment: @StellaBiderman This question was posted in a group-chat on whatsapp, i tried to solve it using geometric approach, my answer is 0.50. Please help ^_^

Comment: @Logophobic Actually the person who sent it was referring to this [berkeley puzzles](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=riddles_hard;action=display;num=1383426919)

Comment: For the case of a finite number of bullets see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526292/colliding-bullets)

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, thanks :-) I saw that question is the plausible cases of the "question already exists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}\sim U(0,1)$. For all positive integers $n$ and $j$ we have
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=n+1}^{n+j}\{X_k\leqslant X_n\} \right) = 2^{-j}, $$
and $$\bigcap_{k=n+1}^{n+j}\{X_k\leqslant X_n\}\supset \bigcap_{k=n+1}^{n+1+j}\{X_k\leqslant X_n\}, $$
and therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\{X_k\leqslant X_n\} \right)  &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\{X_k\leqslant X_n\} \right)\\
&= \lim_{j\to\infty}P\left(\bigcap_{k=n+1}^{n+j}\{X_k\leqslant X_n\} \right)\\
&= \lim_{j\to\infty}2^{-j}\\
&=0.
\end{align}
Hence
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n+1}^\infty\{X_k\leqslant X_n\} \right) \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=n+1}^\infty\{X_k\leqslant X_n\} \right)=0,
$$
so that
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n+1}^\infty\{X_k> X_n\} \right) = 1 - \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n+1}^\infty\{X_k\leqslant X_n\} \right)=1. $$
For each bullet $n$, there is a bullet $k>n$ traveling faster than bullet $n$ with probability $1$. It follows that the probability of at least one bullet flying forever without collision is zero.

Comment: Your answer is most probably correct. I'm waiting for someone to show  otherwise (am y other answers) .

Comment: It's possible that a bullet will travel forever even if there's a later, faster bullet (because some third bullet interposes itself between them).

Comment: This answer to the question is counter-intuitive :-) Should I write my approach ? And then mark it as community wiki so that everyone can critique.

Comment: @ABcDexter By all means.

Comment: @Math1000 Posting my answer...